when deploying DJANGO app in CPANEL, but only the home page works
This is my urls:
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('TEST/', views.test, name='test')

home has button that redirect to test.
I am not using any login, database or anything, just 2 html pages. but only when the path is '' that is working.
I tryed on localhost and pythanywhere and it's working prefectly. the probleme only occur on Cpanel.
the TEST/ page says : file not found.
i have debbug ON in settings.py but it doesn't give more details.

you are passing same view for 2 urls views.test

add views code to your question pls

Please go to URL TEST/ with your template tags for url and provide output. This is nearly impossible to answer right now, we have nothing to go on. This is why downvote

i made a mistake its :
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('TEST/', views.test, name='test')
the views:
def home(request):
return render(request, 'home.html')
def test(request):
return render(request, 'TEST.html')

hi @CSofiane please do not answer the question in comment, question must be edited and answer must be post as answer not comment also read How do I ask a good question? and How do I write a good answer?
